# Producing a path from each node to the root of a tree represented as edges in a table

Tags: postgresql, tree, hierarchy, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have the following table on a PostgreSQL database (parent_fk is a foreign key that references the same table):

```
id    |    parent_fk
72    |    
342   |    72
583   |    342
```

I want to query this table and discover the path of each element to the ultimate parent via intermediate parent/child relationships. For example, I would like to obtain the following as the answer to an SQL query:

```
id    |    parent_fk    |    path
72    |                 |     72
342   |    72           |    72;342
583   |    342          |   72;342;583
```

I read about CTE (Common Table Expressions) and recursive queries on PostgreSQL but I couldn't solve this problem by myself yet. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for showing the expected result.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may want to examine the [`ltree` contrib module](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ltree.html) if you're doing much of this sort of thing.

Here's a CTE that'll do the job, see [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/b9850/3):

```
WITH RECURSIVE x(id,parent_fk,parents,last_id, depth) AS (
  SELECT id, parent_fk, ARRAY[id] AS parents, id AS last_id, 0 AS depth FROM table1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT x.id, x.parent_fk, parents||t1.parent_fk, t1.parent_fk AS last_id, x.depth + 1
  FROM x 
    INNER JOIN table1 t1 
    ON (last_id= t1.id)
  WHERE t1.parent_fk IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT id, parent_fk, array_to_string(parents,';')
FROM x 
WHERE depth = (SELECT max(sq.depth) FROM x sq WHERE sq.id = x.id);
```

Your table is a representation of a *directed graph* as a set of *edges*. You've specified that the graph is a tree, meaning that it's acyclic. What you want to do is to find the path from each node (inner or leaf) on the tree to the root and represent that as a semi-colon separated string.

Comment: Wow! What a perfect answer. The ltree module is very interesting. Your script has also worked perfectly. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: @FernandoMagalhães Glad to help. Somewhat improved version added in an edit; it avoids the repeated `array_length` calls. Note that if you're working with lots of data you should give this query as much `work_mem` as you can afford, as it requires repeated sorting.

Comment: About the max(parents): max(parents) does not always select the longest array. The query: select max(t.a1) from (select array[2] as a1 union all select array[1,1]) t for example returns {2} instead of returning the longest {1,1} array. It seems that max(array[]) function compares each array elements one by one instead of comparing the size of the arrays.

Comment: @FernandoMagalhães Thanks for confirming. I didn't test in depth, which is why I posted a second safer version. Removing the flawed 1st version now.

Comment: Very interesting. 6 years later I wonder whether this approach / ltree is still the way to go here